# Set default compiler when using Cython and setuptools to compile multiple extensions

Tags: python, compilation, cython, setuptools

I currently have a project, where we make heavy use of Cython to speed up all of our submodules / classes and I wish to compile them with `clang` instead of `gcc` on a Linux system. To this end I currently have a function that gathers all the extensions in the following way:

```
def extensions():
    try:
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    except ImportError:
        def cythonize(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Hint: Wrapping import of cythonize in extensions()")
            from Cython.Build import cythonize
            return cythonize(*args, **kwargs)

    try:
        import numpy
        lstIncludes = [numpy.get_include()]
    except ImportError:
        lstIncludes = []

    extensionArguments = {
        'include_dirs':
        lstIncludes + ['package/core', 'package/inspect', 'util'],
        'extra_compile_args': compilerArguments,
        'extra_link_args': linkerArguments,
        'define_macros': defineMacros
    }

    return cythonize(
        [Extension("*", ["package/*.pyx"], **extensionArguments),
         Extension("*", ["package/algs/*.pyx"], **extensionArguments),
         Extension("*", ["package/core/*.pyx"], **extensionArguments)],
        compiler_directives=cythonDirectives)
```

Moreover, I set

```
os.environ["CC"] = "clang"
os.environ["CXX"] = "clang"
```

in `setup.py` and when I call `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, the first Cython extension is built using `clang` but the second one is built with `gcc`. This behaviour does not change, if I invoke

```
export CC=clang; python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Then again, the first uncompiled of the cythonized extensions is built using `clang` but the second one and all following are built using `gcc` again.

How can I set and fix the compiler for all Cython modules during compilation?

Edit: After some weeks of consideration I still do not have a solution to above problem and it also occurs across multiple machines, so it is not a result of my specific setup.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2535) about this on the Cython repo.

Answer (score 8):

I finally found out, that it is necessary to forcibly override stuff that `disutils` has extracted from our system configuration. To this end one has to set certain options for each extension separately by modifying above code as follows

```
from distutils import sysconfig

def extensions():
    '''
    Handle generation of extensions (a.k.a "managing cython compilery").
    '''
    try:
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    except ImportError:
        def cythonize(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Hint: Wrapping import of cythonize in extensions()")
            from Cython.Build import cythonize
            return cythonize(*args, **kwargs)

    try:
        import numpy
        lstIncludes = [numpy.get_include()]
    except ImportError:
        lstIncludes = []

    extensionArguments = {
        'include_dirs':
        lstIncludes + ['package/core', 'package/inspect', 'util'],
        'extra_compile_args': compilerArguments,
        'extra_link_args': linkerArguments,
        'define_macros': defineMacros
    }

    # me make damn sure, that disutils does not mess with our
    # build process

    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CFLAGS'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['OPT'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['PY_CFLAGS'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['PY_CORE_CFLAGS'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CC'] = 'gcc'
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CXX'] = 'g++'
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['BASECFLAGS'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CCSHARED'] = '-fPIC'
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['LDSHARED'] = 'gcc -shared'
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CPP'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CPPFLAGS'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['BLDSHARED'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['LDFLAGS'] = ''
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()['PY_LDFLAGS'] = ''

    return cythonize(
        [Extension("*", ["package/*.pyx"], **extensionArguments),
         Extension("*", ["package/algs/*.pyx"], **extensionArguments),
         Extension("*", ["package/core/*.pyx"], **extensionArguments)],
        compiler_directives=cythonDirectives,
        nthreads=4
    )
```

This way one has the full control over anything happening while building the extensions.